# YoYo Game Maker Deployment windows 8(Native & JS) Error

Tags: deployment, game-maker

I am building a game on YOYO GAME MAKER tool. The application fails to deploy on Windows 8, I have installed every thing. The application works fine  on windows (desktop) mode.

---

```
 + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\Ahmad\AppxManifest.xml 
   :String) [Add-AppxPackage], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManag 
   er.Commands.AddAppxPackageCommand

Appx Registration Succeeded
Compile finished: 6:49:29 PM
```

---